# Why won't Xubuntu let me use dual monitors

Tags: display, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, xubuntu

ASUS laptop and Xubuntu (11.10) running off the live CD will give me my dual monitors, but when I install Xubuntu I can't set up dual monitors. When I boot from the live CD both monitors come on even before it is fully booted. But in installed mode "desktop" and "grandr" says only one monitor. The "NVIDIA X Settings" show two monitors, (CRT-0- (ViewSonic VX1937), and DFP-0- (Apple Color LCD)), but the CRT-0- has no information in its window and the "Reset Hardware Defaults" button is grayed out.

Comment: did you try to run the display monitor utility as sudo

Comment: What video card are you using? Is it with NVidia Optimus?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue. This is what I found on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859730&page=3). Hope it helps you.

> Re: 11.10 dual monitor nvidia card problem
>
> Hi folks! I guess I've found a solution for the multiple displays problem... only thanks to you guys.
>
> 1.) disable active drivers (if you have any after fresh install f.e.)
>
> 2.) install nvidia drivers current (not pre-release)
>
> 3.) reboot
>
> 4.) type cd /etc/X11/ and then cp xorg.conf xorg.conf.backup (it makes copy of your configuration file... {just in case})
>
> 5.) open up the terminal and enter: sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
>
> 6.) after installation enter sudo nvidia-settings (it opens up the Nvidia X Server settings)
>
> 7.) goto X Server Display Configuration
>
> 8.) set your settings, BUT! don't hit apply... when you are finished hit Save to X Configuration File
>
> 9.) log off and log in again
>
> and voala it should be done now! I had problems saving my X configuration file but I fixed it by the step number 4